# deploying java plugins in cloud foundry

Tags: java, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have deployed few apps in cloud foundry and i want to see the CPU usage and Memory consumption etc like we see through Jprofile,JMX etc.

So can i deploy them as a plugin in my space if so - what are the steps.
not expecting a full length answer you can give some blog url or reference.
is deploying a plugin is same as application deployment.

Any other way to see the usage .
Because cloud foundry provider shows very basic usage in numbers but what i want is a graphical interface.

Any hint on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To monitor Pivotal Cloud Foundry, there are multiple tools available. 
For platform monitoring you can use [PCF Metrics](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-metrics/1-1/using.html), `Data Dog`, `New Relic`, `Prometheus + Grafana`.

Most of these do need the `JMX Bridge` tile installed.

For app performance monitoring you can install or setup tools like `New Relic` or `App Dynamics`. You will have to pay for these tools.

Register with `network.pivotal.io`. Sign in and you will get a list of all tiles from Pivotal and 3rd party vendors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ... that was really helpful

Comment: I have done it but my reputation is less than 15 so it won't be visible.